# Android Studio Javadoc won't generate because "Selected scope contain no Java classes"

Tags: android, scope, javadoc

I am trying to generate the JavaDoc for the Activity class source code in Android Studio 3.6.3.  The file is open in the editor, and I use "Tools | Generate JavaDoc".  [image]

When I click OK, it fails with the message "**Error running 'Javadoc': Selected scope contain no Java classes**".  I also tried the "Custom Scope" option with "Current File" choice, but same results.

Can someone help why can I not generate the JavaDoc for this file?

Comment: Please share the content of the Activity

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea.  It was someone else's code, so I looked at another project of mine where the build.gradle file for the module has:

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Then I followed the declaration chain in my code for an Activity up to the Activity superclass -- and it goes to the same source file.  I guess my SDK has one source file regardless of the library used.  Anyway, same problem, it won't print the JavaDoc.  I don't understand why it won't print that source file, since it exists.

Answer (score 0):

The file is too large to paste here, it is 410832 characters, only 30000 allowed.

I could paste some of it if that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe JavaDocs needs compiled code with no errors, missing references, etc.  When I open Activity.java, It is not compilable.